# Fetch Record Type Id based on Developer Name without SOQL?

Tags: apex

Salesforce doesn't have  the method `getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName`. They have given only  by record type name.

```
Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('SampeRecName').getRecordTypeId()
```

Comment: AFAIK not possible without SOQL but will be happy to be wrong about that...

Answer (score 14):

Short answer: There's no way to do that.

Long answer: Currently, the only way to access the developer name is to query for it. I'd recommend using an utility class with a static map so you can make just one call per execution.

You can also vote on [this idea.](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000K9zoAAC).

**Update :-**

This is now possible as per [Summer 18 Release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_developer_name.htm)

You can use the following methods to get the developer name.

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName();
Schema.RecordTypeInfo.getDeveloperName();
```

Answer (score 5):

update - it will be possible from Summer'18 https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_developer_name.htm